# Is there any impact of reaping zombie processes?

Tags: process, solaris, zombie-process

I will execute following command for reaping zombie

```
 /usr/bin/preap $(ps -ef | grep defunct | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs)
```

Is there any service impact of this approach ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you reap a zombie before its parent, you lose whatever effect the reaping would have in the parent. This is obviously application-dependent.

There is very little reason to actively go and reap zombies. Some operating systems don't let you do it, short of manually ptracing the parent process and causing it to execute a `waitpid` system call. Solaris offers a `preap` utility, but the only case when you should use it is when a program is misbehaving and filling the process table with zombies.

Comment: it seems that application is misbehaving and zombie processes are only thing I am suspicious about.

Comment: @mibzer Zombie processes are probably a symptom, not the disease. Usually, zombie processes are left behind because the process that should reap them isn't doing what it should be doing (including `wait`ing for its children). Reaping the zombies won't make it do whatever else it should be doing.

Answer (score 3):

Your script might reap zombies too early preventing their parents to reap them and then causing unexpected behavior with them.

Assuming you have no way to fix the root cause of these zombie processes existence, I would only reap those that have been in the defunct state for a long enough period of time (eg. 1 minute) to avoid bypassing legitimate reaping:

```
for pid in $(ps -eo pid,s | nawk '$2 == "Z" {print $1 };sleep 60)
do
  preap $pid
done
```

By the way, `| xargs` is useless in your script as a new line is a valid argument separator.

Comment: What is “too early”? What are the downsides of reaping them too soon? How to determine “long enough”?

Comment: That's a timing issue. If you happen to run your script just after a process dies, you need to let its parent process a chance to reap it and properly get its return status.

Comment: You would never know how long to wait. Better to let the parent do its job and fix it if it's not.

Comment: @Jim Paris: I agree the root cause should be fixed if possible but I assume the question means it is not possible for some reason. In any case, if the parent has not reaped a defunct child after say one minute, there is very little chance it will ever do it.

Comment: Here is a counterexample that took no time to find: [monit](http://old.nabble.com/monit-%22check-program%22-reap-interval-td34015312.html) starts a program at regular intervals but doesn't reap them until the following interval starts, perhaps five minutes later.

Comment: @Jim Paris: Indeed, there are cases where one minute won't be long enough and that's why I wrote "very little chance" and not "no chance at all". I'm assuming mibzer has no way to fix the root cause which rules out monit.

Comment: that was 1 example, I'm sure there are many more. The point is that you don't need to fix the root cause because there's no problem.

Comment: if you have zombie processes who's parent pid is '1' (init), those you can reap.  If a zombie process still reports it's actual parent as it's PPID, wait it out.